# Find the indices of positive elements in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to return an array of indices of an array which has positive elements using pure functions in JS. EX:

`pos([1,-4,0,5,2])`

```
>>[0,2,3,4]
```

So, I tried:

```
  arr.map(function (ele){
   return arr.findIndex(ele => ele > 0);
  })

But my output is :[1,1,1,1]
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong? I believe that my map function is correct but something is wrong with findIndex(). (Please don't tell me the code as it is a question of my assignment. Only need hints.)

Answer (score 2):

You could first map the index, if the value is positive or `-1` and then filter the array for existing indices.

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array with the index of the element or `-1` if the element is smaller than zero.

[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns all values which are not `-1`. The short adding just one returns a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value which is a possible index.

```js
function pos(array) {
    return array                       // [1, -4, 0, 5, 2]
        .map((v, i) => v < 0 ? -1 : i) // [0, -1, 2, 3, 4]
        .filter(i => i + 1);           // [0,     2, 3, 4]
}

console.log(pos([1, -4, 0, 5, 2]));
```

Your callback for mapping

```js
function pos(arr) {
    return arr.map(function (ele) {
        return arr.findIndex(ele => ele > 0);
    });
}

console.log(pos([1, -4, 0, 5, 2]));
```

takes no element, because the first `ele` variable is never used later. Then you return always the index of the first element of `arr`, which is `1`. This value is greater as zero and the callback for `find` returns `true` abd find hands over the actual index.

Comment: Can you explain me the way in which you have used the filter? I didn't get that

Comment: @Vagabond Maybe better `.filter(i => i != -1)`

Answer (score 1):

`map()` isn't quite right because you won't have corresponding output for every element in the original array. `reduce()` is probably what you want in this case:

```js
function pos(arr){
    return arr.reduce((ret_arr, number, index) => {
        if (number >= 0) ret_arr.push(index)
        return ret_arr
    }, [])

}

console.log(pos([1,-4,0,5,2]))
```

Comment: Why are you using reduce()? maps makes more sense as they are going to iterate all the objects. Reduce is going to collect all the objects according to the condition test.

Comment: @Vagabond, you are right `reduce` will collect all the objects according to a test. But that is precisely what you want. Your result `[0,2,3,4]` is a collection of objects that passed the test of having corresponding values greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `findIndex`. Basically you are looking for

```
function pos(arr) {
    var res = [];
    for (const [index, el] of arr.entries())
        if (el > 0)
            res.push(index)
    return res;
}
```

If you want to do this using the higher-order array methods, you could do

```
function pos(arr) {
    return arr.map((ele, index) => [ele, index])
              .filter(([ele]) => ele > 0)
              .map(([_, origIndex]) => origIndex);
}
```

@NinaScholz has a good approach as well, though I'd write it as

```
function pos(arr) {
    return arr.map((ele, index) => ele > 0 ? index : null)
              .filter(index => index !== null);
}
```

Comment: Why would you `map` and `filter` making multiple passes through the arrays rather than making a single pass with `reduce`? If the original array is all positive numbers you will look at each one twice.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Because I don't want to reduce it to a single value, I want to keep an array. And there's a distinct one-to-one-or-none mapping, which is where `map` and `filter` excel. The `reduce` solution is equivalent to the `for … of` loop I've written (but either less efficient, or giving it a "functional touch" that it shouldn't have).

Comment: @MarkMeyer If you argue about the single pass vs multiple passes, you could look into transducers which allow to fuse the callbacks into a single pass, or implement an (indexed) [`mapMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe) equivalent for JS.

Comment: I suppose the argument that reduce is only for single values might make some sense, but I don't really see it in common practice — people are constantly using it to make hash tables, objects, and other things that are not single values. As far as efficiency — reduce appears to wins at least on safari and chrome: https://jsperf.com/map-filter-or-reduce through I suspect a regular `for` loop rather than `for...of` would still win.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I consider a hash table (and other composites) to be a single object as well - my point was that the output type is still an array, and about the size of the input array.

Comment: I guess I'll just be content with respectfully disagreeing — if one can consider a hash table a single entity, one can consider an array of indexes a single entity.  I appreciate  the discussion - thanks.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yes, we can consider it that. And using `reduce` does of course work, it is more flexible and generic than `map`. In many functional languages `map` is even implemented in terms of `reduce`. So why do we use `map` (or `filter`) at all if we could always use `reduce`? Because it is simpler - we don't have to specify the `[]` initial value, we don't have to use `push` (or list cons)!

Comment: @MarkMeyer When reducing to a hash table, we just don't have the choice - if there was a direct conversion function available, we would use it. Or actually there is: instead of `arr.reduce((m, x) => m.set(x.key, x.value), new Map)` we could use the cleaner `new Map(arr.map(x => [x.key, x.value]))`. Same here: it there was a [`filter_mapi` function](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/List/#val-filter_mapi) in JS, everyone would be using it instead of `reduce`. In my answer I just tried to implement it using `filter`+`map` individually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[1,-4,0,5,2].reduce((acc,value,i) => value >= 0 ? [...acc,i] : acc,[]);
```

In any case where you're ding both filtering and ?something-else? reduce is always the best option. 
For basic algorithms like this try returning a new array containing the previous values via spread.

Answer (score 0):

```
const possitive = [];
const negative = [];
const array = [-1, -2, 0, 4, 1, 3, 2];

// Separate negative from possitive values
array.map(number =>
  number >= 0 ? possitive.push(number) : negative.push(number)
);

// Sort accessing order
possitive.sort((a, b) => a - b);
negative.sort((a, b) => a - b);

// Join both arrays
const completed = possitive.concat(negative);

// Console log completed array
console.log(completed);

//Result
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -2, -1];
```